# How can we store a string in 7 bit format?

Tags: c++

I have a requirement where I need to save memory by converting 16 bit string to 7 bit string. I need to use utf-7 for achieving the same. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

```
   Decimal   Octal   Hex    Binary     Value
   -------   -----   ---    ------     -----
     000      000    000   00000000      NUL    (Null char.)
     001      001    001   00000001      SOH    (Start of Header)
     002      002    002   00000010      STX    (Start of Text)
     003      003    003   00000011      ETX    (End of Text)
     004      004    004   00000100      EOT    (End of Transmission)
     005      005    005   00000101      ENQ    (Enquiry)
     006      006    006   00000110      ACK    (Acknowledgment)
     007      007    007   00000111      BEL    (Bell)
     008      010    008   00001000       BS    (Backspace)
     009      011    009   00001001       HT    (Horizontal Tab)
     010      012    00A   00001010       LF    (Line Feed)
     011      013    00B   00001011       VT    (Vertical Tab)
     012      014    00C   00001100       FF    (Form Feed)
     013      015    00D   00001101       CR    (Carriage Return)
     014      016    00E   00001110       SO    (Shift Out)
     015      017    00F   00001111       SI    (Shift In)
     016      020    010   00010000      DLE    (Data Link Escape)
     017      021    011   00010001      DC1    (XON) (Device Control 1)
     018      022    012   00010010      DC2          (Device Control 2)
     019      023    013   00010011      DC3    (XOFF)(Device Control 3)
     020      024    014   00010100      DC4          (Device Control 4)
     021      025    015   00010101      NAK    (Negative Acknowledgement)
     022      026    016   00010110      SYN    (Synchronous Idle)
     023      027    017   00010111      ETB    (End of Trans. Block)
     024      030    018   00011000      CAN    (Cancel)
     025      031    019   00011001       EM    (End of Medium)
     026      032    01A   00011010      SUB    (Substitute)
     027      033    01B   00011011      ESC    (Escape)
     028      034    01C   00011100       FS    (File Separator)
     029      035    01D   00011101       GS    (Group Separator)
     030      036    01E   00011110       RS    (Request to Send)(Record Separator)
     031      037    01F   00011111       US    (Unit Separator)
     032      040    020   00100000       SP    (Space)
     033      041    021   00100001        !    (exclamation mark)
     034      042    022   00100010        "    (double quote)
     035      043    023   00100011        #    (number sign)
     036      044    024   00100100        $    (dollar sign)
     037      045    025   00100101        %    (percent)
     038      046    026   00100110        &    (ampersand)
     039      047    027   00100111        '    (single quote)
     040      050    028   00101000        (    (left/opening parenthesis)
     041      051    029   00101001        )    (right/closing parenthesis)
     042      052    02A   00101010        *    (asterisk)
     043      053    02B   00101011        +    (plus)
     044      054    02C   00101100        ,    (comma)
     045      055    02D   00101101        -    (minus or dash)
     046      056    02E   00101110        .    (dot)
     047      057    02F   00101111        /    (forward slash)
     048      060    030   00110000        0
     049      061    031   00110001        1
     050      062    032   00110010        2
     051      063    033   00110011        3
     052      064    034   00110100        4
     053      065    035   00110101        5
     054      066    036   00110110        6
     055      067    037   00110111        7
     056      070    038   00111000        8
     057      071    039   00111001        9
     058      072    03A   00111010        :    (colon)
     059      073    03B   00111011        ;    (semi-colon)
     060      074    03C   00111100        <    (less than)
     061      075    03D   00111101        =    (equal sign)
     062      076    03E   00111110        >    (greater than)
     063      077    03F   00111111        ?    (question mark)
     064      100    040   01000000        @    (AT symbol)
     065      101    041   01000001        A
     066      102    042   01000010        B
     067      103    043   01000011        C
     068      104    044   01000100        D
     069      105    045   01000101        E
     070      106    046   01000110        F
     071      107    047   01000111        G
     072      110    048   01001000        H
     073      111    049   01001001        I
     074      112    04A   01001010        J
     075      113    04B   01001011        K
     076      114    04C   01001100        L
     077      115    04D   01001101        M
     078      116    04E   01001110        N
     079      117    04F   01001111        O
     080      120    050   01010000        P
     081      121    051   01010001        Q
     082      122    052   01010010        R
     083      123    053   01010011        S
     084      124    054   01010100        T
     085      125    055   01010101        U
     086      126    056   01010110        V
     087      127    057   01010111        W
     088      130    058   01011000        X
     089      131    059   01011001        Y
     090      132    05A   01011010        Z
     091      133    05B   01011011        [    (left/opening bracket)
     092      134    05C   01011100        \    (back slash)
     093      135    05D   01011101        ]    (right/closing bracket)
     094      136    05E   01011110        ^    (caret/circumflex)
     095      137    05F   01011111        _    (underscore)
     096      140    060   01100000        `
     097      141    061   01100001        a
     098      142    062   01100010        b
     099      143    063   01100011        c
     100      144    064   01100100        d
     101      145    065   01100101        e
     102      146    066   01100110        f
     103      147    067   01100111        g
     104      150    068   01101000        h
     105      151    069   01101001        i
     106      152    06A   01101010        j
     107      153    06B   01101011        k
     108      154    06C   01101100        l
     109      155    06D   01101101        m
     110      156    06E   01101110        n
     111      157    06F   01101111        o
     112      160    070   01110000        p
     113      161    071   01110001        q
     114      162    072   01110010        r
     115      163    073   01110011        s
     116      164    074   01110100        t
     117      165    075   01110101        u
     118      166    076   01110110        v
     119      167    077   01110111        w
     120      170    078   01111000        x
     121      171    079   01111001        y
     122      172    07A   01111010        z
     123      173    07B   01111011        {    (left/opening brace)
     124      174    07C   01111100        |    (vertical bar)
     125      175    07D   01111101        }    (right/closing brace)
     126      176    07E   01111110        ~    (tilde)
     127      177    07F   01111111      DEL    (delete)
```

if I am correct we are not utilizing the 8th bit(0 in all binary values). So i have a requirement where this memory needs to be saved. I know that for storing in 7 bits we need to encode the string in utf-7 format. But I have no idea how to encode a utf-16 string to utf-7.

The reason for the requirement is, we have a oracle database where we store data in tables. Now I know that once a table is created and memory allocated we cannot save any memory from that. However, I have a requirement to find a way to save memory. In my table I have a column where i enter strings and while creating the table i have allocated 1024 bytes of memory for that column.

Comment: First figure out how the 16-bit string is encoded and then an algorithm to convert from that encoding to utf-7. I don't see how you'll save memory unless all the characters fit into single utf-7 units, in which case why is there a 16-bit string in the first place.

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty simple [algorithm explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7#Encoding).

Comment: We need to know a bit more about your application.  Do you want to pack 8 of these characters into 7 `char` values? If not, I would **strongly** recommend using UTF-8.  Depending on the text you are encoding, it will either be more compact or no worse.  It is also a widely understood encoding.

Comment: You can't save characters in 7 bits, simply because you can't save anything in less than a single byte = 8 bits. You can achieve some **dubious** space reduction  If and **ONLY** if the string is UTF16 **AND** it contains ANSI characters only, you can convert it to plain old ANSI. In any other case you'll need **multiple** bytes for each UTF16 pair

Comment: Dumping a character table isn't going to help anyone

Comment: @DeiDei: You don't need *all* of the characters to fit in order to save memory - you just need *most* of them to fit.  For example this comment will be much more compact in UTF-7/8 than in UTF-16, but it can't be encoded in US-ASCII because of this char:ß

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You can't save a *single* character in less than 8 bits, but you can certainly pack 8 seven bit characters into seven `char` values.

Comment: What are you trying to do and **why**?  C++ doesn't have a UTF8 type, although it does have UTF16 (char16_t) and UTF32 (char32_t) types. For UTF8 you use plain old `char` and `std::string`. Unless you take extreme care to make sure you never mix up codepages, and always treat all `char` arrays and strings as UTF8, you can mangle your data

Comment: @MartinBonner yes. Which defeats the purpose of this question - how to save space by converting wide or UTF16 strings into something else

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: ??? Packing EIGHT characters into SEVEN chars saves space.

Comment: @MartinBonner bits, not characters. The OP is asking how to save in 7 bits. You can't. You'll use a byte even if the last bit isn't used

Comment: utf-7 is not intended to save space. It's intended for transfer in places that don't support 8-bit data. I suggest you read up on it.

Comment: To the OP: Do you need to store other characters (like ß, é, or £), or are you already limited to the ASCII character set.

Comment: Thanks guys for the information provided. The reason for the requirement is, we have a oracle database where we store data in tables. Now I know that once a table is created and memory allocated we cannot save any memory from that. However, I have a requirement to find a way to save memory. In my table I have a column where i enter strings and while creating the table i have allocated 1024 bytes of memory for that column.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: But usually you don't store single characters, you store sequences of them.  A sequence will take ceil(7*no-of-chars/8) bytes.  If your sequences are >= characters long, then you save space.  If you have enough of them, that will compensate for the packing/unpacking code.

Comment: @MartinBonner then you don't have strings, you have a sequence of bytes that no longer represent characters and require decoding of the entire buffer to have any meaning. No different than compressing this actually. That's not what this question is about.

Comment: @MartinBonner At this point i need to only store regular ASCII characters. Just plain strings. Ex: "Hello, World"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I think this is exactly what this question is about.  What makes you think it isn't.

Comment: @MartinBonner the word `string` and the mention of UTF7. Nothing suggest bit packing

Comment: If you are going to mangle the text such that you can't query against it, you can put in into a lookup table and replace the text column with a short FK (say, int), saving a ton of bytes in the base record.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use UTF-7, use UTF-8.

This is almost always as compact as UTF-7, and if you have any non-ASCII characters, a lot *more* compact.  It is also much, *much* easier to work with.  Finally, it is an extremely well supported standard, and there is a very high chance you can ask Oracle to store a string as UTF-8, but return it to you as a UTF-16 string.

If you can't get Oracle to do the conversion, you can get your operating system to do it.  Both Posix and Windows have UTF-8 <-> UTF-16 conversion functions.

Comment: We already have implemented the mentioned UTF-8. How ever, I have been asked to find a way to store the characters of string in 7 bits. As far as I have researched, I came to know to store a string in 7 bit format I need to use UTF-7.

Comment: If you already using UTF-8, you would be better using a compression library like zlib.  Depending on how you use it, this can give *much* better compression than just "7 bits per character".  If you only care about compressing long strings, and your text is typical English, I would expect about 4 bits per char.

Comment: Is Zlib a third party library or an inbuild library of C++. I am not allowed to use any third party libraries.

Comment: It's a third party open source C library with a very liberal license.  If your job requires you to reinvent the wheel, find another job.